# How to combine two dataframes conditionally and the write the output as a text file?

Tags: python

My dataset consists of two data frames. For example, df1 and df2 for simplicity (actual dataset is large)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'P1': [2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                    'P2': [1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5],
                    'P3': [1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1],
                    'P4': [6, 2.3, 8.8, 4.6, 5.3, 7],
                    'P5': [11.4, 18, 18.8, 25, 12, 27.4],
                    'P6': [32.44, 31.56, 18, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95]
                   })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D1': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
                    'D2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'D3': [5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 10, 11, 12, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6],
                    'D4': [6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7, 6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7,6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7],
                    'D5': [11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4, 11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4, 11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4],
                    'D6': [32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95, 32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95, 32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95],
                    'ST': ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL', 'ZY', 'ST', 'QD', 'YT', 'RT', 'EW', 'SD', 'FF']
                   })
```

I require combining them iteratively by picking the first row (then second and so on) of df1 (write on a text file) and then scan over the df2 and select rows if

```
df3 =df1['p4'] == df2['D4'] and df1['p5'] == df2['D5'] and df1['p6'] == df2['D6']
```

(write df3 on the same text file)

This process repeat iteratively till length of df1 and then generate a text file in such a format.
In most of the cases, condition is not fulfilled then write a line with 'No event'

**Expected output**

```
0  2019   1   1  6.0  11.4  32.44
1 2019   1   5  6.0  11.4  32.44  AB
2 2019   6  10  6.0  11.4  32.44  IJ
3 2018   1   5  6.0  11.4  32.44  YT
4 2019   2   1  2.3  18.0  31.56
5 2019   2   6  2.3  18.0  31.56  BC
6 2019   7  11  2.3  18.0  31.56  KL
7 2018   2   4  2.3  18.0  31.56  RT
8 2018   8   8  8.8  18.8  18.00
No event
```

**Here is what I did so far**:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'P1': [2019, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                    'P2': [1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 5],
                    'P3': [1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1],
                    'P4': [6, 2.3, 8.8, 4.6, 5.3, 7],
                    'P5': [11.4, 18, 18.8, 25, 12, 27.4],
                    'P6': [32.44, 31.56, 18, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95]
                   })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D1': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
                    'D2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    'D3': [5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 10, 11, 12, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6],
                    'D4': [6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7, 6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7,6, 2.3, 4.6, 5.3, 7],
                    'D5': [11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4, 11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4, 11.4, 18, 25, 12, 27.4],
                    'D6': [32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95, 32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95, 32.44, 31.56, 33.01, 31.24, 31.95],
                    'ST': ['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'EF', 'GH', 'IJ', 'KL', 'ZY', 'ST', 'QD', 'YT', 'RT', 'EW', 'SD', 'FF']
                   })
L=len(df1)

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
    
    for i in range(L):
        a=df1.loc[[i]]
        f.write(a, /n)
        C1=a['P4']
        C2=a['P5']
        C3=a['P6']
        if df3 = df2[(df2['D4'] == C1) and df2['D5']==C2 and df2['D6']==C3]
        f.write(df3, /n)
        else
        f.write(n/,'no event'/n)

print(df1)
```

My script is still not producing the required result. May someone suggest how I can improve or update the script.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, there are, in such case i need to scan over the whole dataframe and pick all of them as far as satisfying the condition.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I hadn't carefully looked at the output so my comment was unnecessary.

Comment: So what is wrong with your existing code (other than the typos in what you posted)?

Comment: No output, so for. Number of errors

Comment: There is no `&&` in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi noticed a couple of issues in the code provided:

1. The `if` and `else` statements are not indented properly and missing a `:`
2. When writing to a file you need to pass a string (not a pandas object)
3. As you wish to write multiple lines (should multiple columns of `df2` match with the selected column in `df1`) you will need to loop over `df2` as well
4. `f.write()` only takes one argument if you want to add a linebreak (`'\n'` instead of `'/n'`) you will have to do so in a separate call
5. The example output you have provided includes elements not mentioned in the if statement, I have added some although I am not sure if these are the desired elements

Here are the mentioned changes applied to your code:

```
L1 = len(df1)
L2 = len(df2)

with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:   
    for i in range(L1):
        a = df1.loc[i]
        f.write(str([element for element in a]))
        f.write('\n')
        found_line = False
        
        for j in range(L2):
            b = df2.loc[j]
            if (b['D4'] == a['P4']) and (b['D5'] == a['P5']) and (b['D6'] == a['P6']):
                elements = [b['D1'], b['D2'], b['D3'],  a['P4'], a['P5'], a['P6'], b['ST']]
                f.write(str(elements))
                f.write('\n')
                found_line = True
                
        if not found_line:
            f.write('no event \n')
            break
```

This results in the following .txt file

```
[2019.0, 1.0, 1.0, 6.0, 11.4, 32.44]
[2019, 1, 5, 6.0, 11.4, 32.44, 'AB']
[2019, 6, 10, 6.0, 11.4, 32.44, 'IJ']
[2018, 1, 5, 6.0, 11.4, 32.44, 'YT']
[2019.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.3, 18.0, 31.56]
[2019, 2, 6, 2.3, 18.0, 31.56, 'BC']
[2019, 7, 11, 2.3, 18.0, 31.56, 'KL']
[2018, 2, 4, 2.3, 18.0, 31.56, 'RT']
[2018.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.8, 18.8, 18.0]
no event
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I think still there is some bug in code. Because, when i used the else condition, then code only pick one row if condition satisfy and ignore other.

Comment: That's the point I'm not too sure about which is why my code does not include an `else` statement. Do you wish to write `'no event'` as soon as a column in `df1` does not match any in `df2`?

Comment: Yes, if there is no match then it should print as no event

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer and added a flag to my code this should produce the desired result now

Comment: I tested again, but if there is no line code stop there, but it should move to next event and start iteration again. It fine, i have updated the script now it works well. Thanks a lot for help